# Adding a list of space separated numbers

Tags: shell, sh

Currently stuck in a situation where I ask the user to input a line of numbers with a space in between, then have the program display those numbers with a delay, then add them. I have everything down, but can't seem to figure out a line of code to coherently calculate the sum of their input, as most of my attempts end up with an error, or have the final number multiplied by the 2nd one (not even sure how?). Any help is appreciated.

```
echo Enter a line of numbers to be added.
read NUMBERS

COUNTER=0 

for NUM in $NUMBERS
do

    sleep 1
    COUNTER=`expr $COUNTER + 1`
    if [ "$NUM" ]; then
        echo "$NUM"
    fi
done
```

I've tried echo `expr $NUM + $NUM` to little success, but this is really all I can some up with.

Comment: You realize that your `COUNTER` is just a running sum of a bunch of 1s, right? Replace `COUNTER` with `sum` and `1` with `$NUM`, and you have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set two variables *n* and *m*, store their sum in *$x*, print it:

```
n=5 m=7 x=$((n + m)) ; echo $x
```

Output:

```
12
```

---

The above syntax is POSIX compatible, (i.e. works in `dash`, `ksh`, `bash`, etc.); from `man dash`:

```
   Arithmetic Expansion
     Arithmetic expansion provides a mechanism for evaluating an arithmetic
     expression and substituting its value.  The format for arithmetic expan‐
     sion is as follows:

           $((expression))

     The expression is treated as if it were in double-quotes, except that a
     double-quote inside the expression is not treated specially.  The shell
     expands all tokens in the expression for parameter expansion, command
     substitution, and quote removal.

     Next, the shell treats this as an arithmetic expression and substitutes
     the value of the expression.
```

---

Two one-liners that do most of the job in the OP:

1. POSIX:

   ```
   while read x ; do echo $(( $(echo $x | tr ' ' '+') )) ; done
   ```
2. `bash`:

   ```
   while read x ; do echo $(( ${x// /+} )) ; done
   ```
3. `bash` with `calc`, (allows summing real, rational & complex numbers, as well as sub-operations):

   ```
   while read x ; do calc -- ${x// /+} ; done
   ```

   Example input line, followed by output:

   ```
   -8!^(1/3) 2^63 -1                   
   9223372036854775772.7095244707464171953
   ```

Comment: Using `$(( ${x// /+} ))` (double slash, instead of single) could enter any number of numbers...

Comment: @jm666, Thanks, now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Start with

```
NUMBERS="4 3 2 6 5 1"
echo $NUMBERS
```

Your script can be changed into

```
sum=0
for NUM in ${NUMBERS}
do    
    sleep 1
    ((counter++))
    (( sum += NUM ))
   echo "Digit ${counter}: Sum=$sum"
done
echo Sum=$sum
```

Another way is using `bc`, usefull for input like `1.6 2.3`

```
sed 's/ /+/g' <<< "${NUMBERS}" | bc
```